# Band gap in insulator

Tags: electronic-band-theory

I know that insulators have big band gap and electrons normally can't cross the gap unless they are excited by some certain photons. Is it possible to apply an extremely large electric field so that an insulator can also conduct electricity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Zener tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Zener_formula) effect that is what happens in [Zener diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode)

Comment: Interesting...my professor told me it is impossible to increase the momentum of electrons in insulators by simply applying electric field. I guess it's because this is an introductory quantum mechanics class so my professor does not want to discuss more complicated concepts.

Comment: Typically in insulators, the breakdown  via voltage or electric field is a destructive effect that alters the material in the process. The zener breakdown is typically not destructive and why zener diodes are made from semiconductors and not insulators